# NSPopUpButton in NSToolbar such annoying

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

**Problem solved!:**

Just check the "Unified Title And Toolbar" option of the NSWindow and the 1pixel-down problem goes away!

[image]

To change the toolbar height just select the **Toolbar Item - Custom View** and change size in the *Size inspector*.

**==============================**

If you know Xcode 5s layout than you should recognise this:

[image: xcode 5 targets]

I want to build it for my own. So I dragged a Toolbar in the Window and added a NSPopUpButton. Then I changed the PopUp Button Cell Style to Radio and turned off the Arrows. So far so good.

[image]

The first thing I noticed is that the Toolbars has different heights. Does anybody know how to change this behaviour (without subclassing NSToolbar)?

The second and more annoying thing I noticed is that if I choose an Item from the PopUp Button the Image for the NSMenuItem move 1 pixel down.

EDIT: Xcode NSMenuItems don't move 1pixel down

[image]

Any suggestions about that thing?

Answer (score 1):

NSToolbar, sadly, can’t really be subclassed. It’s a poorly-written class that tries to be very “magic,” so it’s not even a subclass of NSView—you can’t control how it draws at all, it creates a private view.

You can set its “sizeMode” but I assume you’ve already done that and found that the number of pixels high isn’t what you want.

The easiest thing to do is just leave space for your widgets at the top of your window (above the document content) and have autolayout position your buttons for you. (I haven’t been able to use a real NSToolbar in years because of its limitations.)

As for the popUp menu being mis-aligned with the button: where the menu draws is basically hard-coded, so if you use a button style that NSPopUpButton doesn't expect then the menu will be offset some.

If you’ve already tried just unchecking the “draws border” flag on a default-style NSPopUpButton (one fresh off the palette), There are two solutions for to try: One is to keep trying different buttonStyles that look correct to your eye until you find one that’s not offset. Two is to leave the buttonStyle do the default for NSPopUpButtons but subclass the buttonCell and have it not draw the border (but still leave room for it).